# How to use multiple fetch request result arrays in cellForRow at indexPath

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3, nsfetchrequest

I am stuck as to how I would set up the contents of my cell to display information from multiple entity object instances. In the same cell I need to display the floor number which is in [Floors], the room type which is in [Rooms], the sensor type [Alarms] and the sensor status found in the same array. 
First i am confused as to what I should do in numberOfRowsInSection function. What would be the array to count. 
Second is the cell for row at index path function. Again I need to get the correct index path of the correct array. I suppose that it has something to do with the relations between the entities but i am not sure that would be the correct way.
Could someone take a bit of time and help me out please? Code listing below and pictures. Thank you.

```
class InspectTheSystemTableVC: UITableViewController {

//MARK: - Properties

private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

private var storedFloors = [Floors]()

private var storedRooms = [Rooms]()

private var storedAlarms = [Alarms]()

//MARK: - Actions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    loadFloorData()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

private func loadFloorData() {
    let floorRequest: NSFetchRequest<Floors> = Floors.fetchRequest()
    let roomsRequest: NSFetchRequest<Rooms> = Rooms.fetchRequest()
    let alarmRequest: NSFetchRequest<Alarms> = Alarms.fetchRequest()

    floorRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    roomsRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    alarmRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(floorRequest)
        storedRooms = try managedObjectContext.fetch(roomsRequest)
        storedAlarms = try managedObjectContext.fetch(alarmRequest)
    }
    catch {
        print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "system cell", for: indexPath) as! SystemCell

    return cell
}
```

}

[image: the cell that needs to display data]

[image: core data entity relation]

Comment: make a different datasource for all the different types and reload the tableview when you switch between them.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but could you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: can you share the code so that i can understand the problem better..?

Comment: are the 3 arrays synchronized? I mean is the data at index 0 matching to the other data in the other arrays at index 0? Or are the 3 arrays out of order?

Comment: they are synchronized. i

Comment: Is there any relationship between Floor, Rooms and alarms in xcdatamodel file. e.g. Floor -> Child rooms and Rooms -> alarms.

Comment: yes there is. I will edit the post with a photo

Comment: done. please have a look

Comment: which code should I add. the vc's that I use to assign values to the attributes?

Comment: You don't need to use several arrays.  You should just fetch `Rooms` (or `Alarms`) and then traverse the relationships to get the attributes of the related `Floors` and `Rooms`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Struct which holds the required array values.

Like:

```swift
   struct Entities {    
        var room = Room()
        var floor = Floor()
        var alarm = Alarms()  
     }
    
     var tableDataSource = [Entites]()
```

Now add required data to entities array by iteration. tableDataSource count will be your number of rows in the section count